# syntax error with update query when join with some table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, inner-join

Here is an API generated query - Not sure what is wrong.

```
UPDATE T123 
SET COL1 = 1, VER1 = VER1 + 1  
INNER JOIN  
    SELECT C1 
    FROM (SELECT T.NUM_FLD C1 FROM WAPTDT_123 T) TAB ON C1 = REQUEST_ID
```

gives me error

> SQL command not properly ended

All columns are present in table, I believe something is wrong with the join and running this command on oracle.

**EDIT**

One more thing is, the

```
SELECT C1 
FROM (SELECT T.NUM_FLD C1 FROM WAPTDT_123 T) TAB
```

part of query is fixed as I am getting from some API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle does not support `join` in the `update` syntax:

```
UPDATE T123
    SET COL1 = 1,
        VER1 = VER1 + 1
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM WAPTDT_123 T WHERE T123.REQUEST_ID = T.NUM_FLD);
```

This is standard SQL and should work in any database.

Your query has other problems as well . . . the subquery is not in parentheses, the `inner join` has no first table.

EDIT:

You can write this query with that subquery:

```
UPDATE T123
    SET COL1 = 1,
        VER1 = VER1 + 1
    WHERE T123.REQUEST_ID IN (SELECT C1 FROM ( SELECT T.NUM_FLD C1 FROM WAPTDT_123 T) TAB );
```

I switched this to an `IN`, just because that is another option.  You could still use `EXISTS`.

Comment: Thanx for your answer but I can not change query like that. see the Edit section of my question above.

Comment: an example with Exists? which one is better in terms of performance as this query might result millons row update.

Comment: @MohdAdnan . . . I tend to be biased toward `exists`, but I think Oracle does a good job optimizing both queries.